# Issues with Kernel on machine

Tags: kernel, boot, pop-os

I'm running pop!_os 22.04 and am having a boot issue and I believe its with the newer Kernel.

When I turn on the computer it sits on the motherboard splash screen for much longer than normal and then goes to a blank screen with the flashing cursor. I can't type anything and nothing seems to work. After I shut it down and power it back on I spam the f10 and f12 keys to see if I can get the BIOS up. Instead i'm greeted with a menu that has the following selections:

Pop!_OS (Pop_OS-current.conf)

Pop!_OS (Pop_OS-oldkern.conf)

Pop!_OS recovery

Reboot Into Firmware Interface

If I select the Pop!_OS (Pop_OS-current.conf) one, I get put back into the blank screen or stuck on the motherboard splash screen. However, when I select Pop!_OS (Pop_OS-oldkern.conf) it boots up just fine and takes me to my login screen and I'm able to log in and use everything normally.

I haven't tried the other 2 options yet. I was wondering if it was possible to remove the current kernel and go back to the older one that is working. Or is there something else I should be doing to get the current kernel to work?

Here's a bit of some info on what I have:

```
uname -r
6.0.6-76060006-generic
```

The one above may be displaying my 'old' kernel as I booted into Pop!_OS (Pop_OS-oldkern.conf)

```
sudo dpkg --list | egrep -i --color 'linux-image|linux-headers|linux-modules'


ii  linux-headers-6.0.12-76060006                 6.0.12-76060006.202212290932~1673966427~22.04~e15d5b5           all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 6.0.12
ii  linux-headers-6.0.12-76060006-generic         6.0.12-76060006.202212290932~1673966427~22.04~e15d5b5           amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 6.0.12 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-6.0.6-76060006                  6.0.6-76060006.202210290932~1669062050~22.04~d94609a            all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 6.0.6
ii  linux-headers-6.0.6-76060006-generic          6.0.6-76060006.202210290932~1669062050~22.04~d94609a            amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 6.0.6 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-generic                         6.0.12.76060006.202212290932~1673966427~22.04~e15d5b5           amd64        Generic Linux kernel headers
rc  linux-image-5.11.0-7620-generic               5.11.0-7620.21~1626191760~21.04~55de9c3                         amd64        Linux kernel image for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-5.11.0-7633-generic               5.11.0-7633.35~1630100930~21.04~ae2753e                         amd64        Linux kernel image for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-5.13.0-7614-generic               5.13.0-7614.14~1631647151~21.04~930e87c                         amd64        Linux kernel image for version 5.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-5.13.0-7620-generic               5.13.0-7620.20~1634827117~21.04~874b071                         amd64        Linux kernel image for version 5.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-5.15.11-76051511-generic          5.15.11-76051511.202112220937~1640185481~21.10~b3a2c21          amd64        Linux kernel image for version 5.15.11 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-5.15.15-76051515-generic          5.15.15-76051515.202201160435~1642693824~21.10~97db1bb          amd64        Linux kernel image for version 5.15.15 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-5.15.23-76051523-generic          5.15.23-76051523.202202110435~1644952300~21.10~96763f1          amd64        Linux kernel image for version 5.15.23 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-5.15.5-76051505-generic           5.15.5-76051505.202111250933~1638201579~21.10~09f1aa7           amd64        Linux kernel image for version 5.15.5 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-5.15.8-76051508-generic           5.15.8-76051508.202112141040~1639505278~21.10~0ede46a           amd64        Linux kernel image for version 5.15.8 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-5.16.11-76051611-generic          5.16.11-76051611.202202230823~1646248261~21.10~2b22243          amd64        Linux kernel image for version 5.16.11 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-5.16.15-76051615-generic          5.16.15-76051615.202203161444~1647964027~21.10~e706226          amd64        Linux kernel image for version 5.16.15 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-5.16.19-76051619-generic          5.16.19-76051619.202204081339~1649696161~22.04~091f44b          amd64        Linux kernel image for version 5.16.19 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-5.17.15-76051715-generic          5.17.15-76051715.202206141358~1655919116~22.04~1db9e34          amd64        Linux kernel image for version 5.17.15 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-5.17.5-76051705-generic           5.17.5-76051705.202204271406~1655476786~22.04~62dd706           amd64        Linux kernel image for version 5.17.5 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-5.18.10-76051810-generic          5.18.10-76051810.202207071639~1659403207~22.04~cb5f582          amd64        Linux kernel image for version 5.18.10 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-5.19.0-76051900-generic           5.19.0-76051900.202207312230~1663791054~22.04~28340d4           amd64        Linux kernel image for version 5.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-5.19.16-76051916-generic          5.19.16-76051916.202210150742~1666053244~22.04~cf07008          amd64        Linux kernel image for version 5.19.16 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-6.0.12-76060006-generic           6.0.12-76060006.202212290932~1673966427~22.04~e15d5b5           amd64        Linux kernel image for version 6.0.12 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-6.0.2-76060002-generic            6.0.2-76060002.202210150739~1666289067~22.04~fe0ce53            amd64        Linux kernel image for version 6.0.2 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-6.0.3-76060003-generic            6.0.3-76060003.202210211149~1666452039~22.04~1891946            amd64        Linux kernel image for version 6.0.3 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-6.0.6-76060006-generic            6.0.6-76060006.202210290932~1669062050~22.04~d94609a            amd64        Linux kernel image for version 6.0.6 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic                           6.0.12.76060006.202212290932~1673966427~22.04~e15d5b5           amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
rc  linux-modules-5.11.0-7620-generic             5.11.0-7620.21~1626191760~21.04~55de9c3                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.11.0-7633-generic             5.11.0-7633.35~1630100930~21.04~ae2753e                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.13.0-7614-generic             5.13.0-7614.14~1631647151~21.04~930e87c                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.13.0-7620-generic             5.13.0-7620.20~1634827117~21.04~874b071                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.15.11-76051511-generic        5.15.11-76051511.202112220937~1640185481~21.10~b3a2c21          amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.15.11 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.15.15-76051515-generic        5.15.15-76051515.202201160435~1642693824~21.10~97db1bb          amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.15.15 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.15.23-76051523-generic        5.15.23-76051523.202202110435~1644952300~21.10~96763f1          amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.15.23 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.15.5-76051505-generic         5.15.5-76051505.202111250933~1638201579~21.10~09f1aa7           amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.15.5 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.15.8-76051508-generic         5.15.8-76051508.202112141040~1639505278~21.10~0ede46a           amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.15.8 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.16.11-76051611-generic        5.16.11-76051611.202202230823~1646248261~21.10~2b22243          amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.16.11 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.16.15-76051615-generic        5.16.15-76051615.202203161444~1647964027~21.10~e706226          amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.16.15 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.16.19-76051619-generic        5.16.19-76051619.202204081339~1649696161~22.04~091f44b          amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.16.19 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.17.15-76051715-generic        5.17.15-76051715.202206141358~1655919116~22.04~1db9e34          amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.17.15 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.17.5-76051705-generic         5.17.5-76051705.202204271406~1655476786~22.04~62dd706           amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.17.5 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.18.10-76051810-generic        5.18.10-76051810.202207071639~1659403207~22.04~cb5f582          amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.18.10 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.19.0-76051900-generic         5.19.0-76051900.202207312230~1663791054~22.04~28340d4           amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.19.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.19.16-76051916-generic        5.19.16-76051916.202210150742~1666053244~22.04~cf07008          amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.19.16 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-6.0.12-76060006-generic         6.0.12-76060006.202212290932~1673966427~22.04~e15d5b5           amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 6.0.12 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-6.0.2-76060002-generic          6.0.2-76060002.202210150739~1666289067~22.04~fe0ce53            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 6.0.2 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-6.0.3-76060003-generic          6.0.3-76060003.202210211149~1666452039~22.04~1891946            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 6.0.3 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-6.0.6-76060006-generic          6.0.6-76060006.202210290932~1669062050~22.04~d94609a            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 6.0.6 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-7620-generic       5.11.0-7620.21~1626191760~21.04~55de9c3                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-7633-generic       5.11.0-7633.35~1630100930~21.04~ae2753e                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-7614-generic       5.13.0-7614.14~1631647151~21.04~930e87c                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-7620-generic       5.13.0-7620.20~1634827117~21.04~874b071                         amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
```

Is it as simple as just purging the 6.0.12 linux-headers modules and image?

Edit:

CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 3700X

GPU: Radeon RX 590

```
df -h /boot/efi

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p1  497M  389M  109M  79% /boot/efi


sudo du -h /boot/efi/EFI
131M    /boot/efi/EFI/Recovery-077A-731F
259M    /boot/efi/EFI/Pop_OS-180200e0-2ae5-40b5-9e3e-9f05a3d148c9
96K     /boot/efi/EFI/systemd
96K     /boot/efi/EFI/BOOT
4.0K    /boot/efi/EFI/Linux
389M    /boot/efi/EFI
```

Comment: purging `linux-headers` isn't going to do anything as linux headers have nothing to do with booting etc. it's linux-image that provides the kernel. So, "old kernel" is 6.0.6, it seems that the "current" would be 6.0.12 - do you by chance have an AMD CPU?

Comment: also, what GPU do you have, and when booting from current, can you switch to another tty (ALT-Fn where n is 1,2,3 etc) ALT-Fn is Alt key plus a function key in case that's not obvious to you

Comment: also, what is the output of `df -h /boot/efi`

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, it's AMD CPU and GPU. Results are 
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p1  497M  389M  109M  79% /boot/efi

Comment: Just attempted to reboot spamming ALT-F1/2/3/... and didn't get anything different.

Comment: no need to spam anything ... boot ... blank screen ... wait a while ... try ALF-F1 etc to switch virtual tty

Comment: Just tried that out and ALT-F2 brought me from the motherboard splash screen to a console login screen. Was able to successfully login

Comment: good, at least now you can do some debugging, checking `dmesg` and `/var/log/*` for errors etc

Comment: I wonder if the issue is that you have a LOT of cruft left over from those 17 or so uninstalled kernels ... what's the output of `sudo du -h /boot/efi/EFI`

Comment: Added more to the post. With dmesg, only mentioned of fail I see are: [    0.000000] tsc: Fast TSC calibration failed
[    4.393525] system76_acpi: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel

Comment: nothing in the logs then to explain the lack of GUI